# Dealing with units in arithmetic operations (multiplication and division)

Tags: design-patterns, algorithms, math

I need to design a function to perform the basic arithmetic operations that are `addition (+)`, `subtraction (-)`, `multiplication (x)`, and `division (/)` between 2 numbers.

That function takes 3 arguments:
-`number1`: composed of a `value` and a `unit`.
-`number2`: compoased of a `value` and a `unit`.
-`operation_type`: one of the 4 aforementioned operations.

and should return:
-`number3`: composed of a `value` and a `unit`.

Returning `number3`'s `value` is easy as all I need to do is use conditional statements to perform the corresponding operation (e.g. `if (operation_type == 'addition') { number3.value = number1.value + number2.value; }` ).

However I'm having difficulties figuring out how I should represent and deal with the `unit` (*for `multiplication` and `subtraction` operations, as for `addition` and `subtraction` it remains the same*) in a way that I can chain up multiple operations and properly update the resulting `unit` every time. Here is an example:

```
operations type: multiplications
number1.unit: Kw
number2.unit: h / user / year
number3.unit: Kwh / user / year  _
                                  |
number1.unit: Kwh / user / year  <-
number2.unit: user
number3.unit: Kwh / year  _
                           |
number1.unit: Kwh / year  <-
number2.unit: year
number3.unit: Kwh
...
```

My only constraint is that the `unit` must initially be represented as a `string` because it is stored in the database, then we can parse parse it into an `object/array` as needed.

Some of the problems I'm facing:
**Q1: how to ensure consistent order in the resulting unit (e.g. `h x Kw` and `Kw x h` should both give `Kwh`)?**
**Q2: how to deal with complex units (e.g. `foo / Kw x h / bar`)?**

And because hope dies last:
**Q3: Are there any known algorithms / design patterns for dealing with this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to deal with physical quantities, then you can choose an n-dimensional system of physical units (length, mass, time, charge, etc.) that fits your domain.  Any physical unit is a product of powers of the fundamental units (positive and negative): e.g. force = mass * length * time^-2.  When you multiply physical quantities, you can just add the powers of the fundamental units.  If you need to handle fractional powers, I would represent them as ratios (1/3), not floating point (0.33333333)

Ordering for human display is largely a matter of custom.  Typically the order is positive powers of mass, length, time in the numerator and denominator, e.g. km-m^2/sec^2.  But there are many exceptions.  For example, Hubble's constant has dimension time^-1, but it is typically expressed as velocity / distance, e.g. km/sec / megaparsec.

As far as I know, C++ is the only *popular* language with a type system powerful enough to *conveniently* verify physical unit balance *at compile time*.  There are several C++ libraries available, including one in Boost.  If you are not using C++, you may want to look at one of them for inspiration.

Comment: F# has units of measure out of the box, Haskell can support them pretty easily as a library, I assume these don't count as popular ;)

Comment: @jk: *As far as I know* evidently wasn't very far.  I wouldn't call Haskell popular; not sure about F#.

Answer (score 1):

I would just create a [lookup table.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table)

It's the fastest way to guarantee that when you get `kW` and `h`, regardless of order, that you'll come back with `kW*h`.

The only downside is if you have a very large number of combinations then it can be a pain to put the table together.